# What is view transformation and model transformation respectively? How do I implement each transformation in simple opengl program?

Tags: opengl, transformations, implementation

I want to know what is view transformation, and what is model transformation respectively, and what methods/functions in opengl could be applied to implement each transformation.
Just simple ways to implement each transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the Model and View are created through basic linear algebra techniques. Both are 4x4 matrices which is a fundamental part of the GLSL language. OpenGL usually has very little to do with their actual creation, but is used to transfer the matrices to the GPU.

OpenGL is the API that allows programs to interact with the GPU, GLSL is a language that can be used to write programs that are executed on the GPU itself. The programs written in GLSL is where the View and Model matrix would be used.